# onChange not firing, want to update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [firstName, setFirstname] = useState('');

<Textbox
    inputId="firstName"
    labelName="Given Name"
    type="text"
    value={firstName}
    onChange={setFirstname(event.target.value)}
/>
```

Want to update the state on the `change event`. It does not fire. any idea's why not? I've also tried this.And it does not fire the `handleChange`.

```
`onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}`
...

const handleChange = (e) => {
   console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code in Sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-euclid-t1sb0

Comment: Its working. https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-carson-ynw9x . Check the console after every key press.

Comment: @shyamo you can try hooks https://stackoverflow.com/a/59233138/6544460.

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` property type is function , make `onChange` as function to fix the issue

```
<Textbox
    inputId="firstName"
    labelName="Given Name"
    type="text"
    value={firstName}
    onChange={event => setFirstname(event.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: thanks Ali, i tried this too and it does not fire onChange

Comment: it worked on the sandbox ,checkout the sandbax https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-volhard-m3wtj

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code snippet, make sure to bind method you are assigning to onChange, like `handleChange` in below code:

```js
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<NameForm />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thanks Sarvesh, how can this be achieved using a functional component instead of a class based component? i am using hooks

Comment: @shyamo, please add detail description, you didn't mention in requirement whether it is a functional or class-based component ?

Comment: i'll be clearer, but my code had hooks and they only be used in functional components

Answer (score 0):

solved it, problem i had i was passing onChange `Textbox` which also contain a label. therefore had to pass onChange prop as a function

e.g.

Textbox component:

```
<label>{labelName}</label>
<input type="text" onChange={onChange} />
```

Parent:

`<Textbox onChange={e => setFirstname(e.target.value)}`

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use multiple `useState` for firstname, middlename, lastname

This is how you can update object in hooks

1-update object in hooks

2-reuse multiple input handling

```
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState({
    firstName:'',
    surname:''
  });

 const handleName=e=>{
   setName({...name, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
 }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{name.firstName}</h1>
      <h1>{name.surname}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <input
        type="text"
        inputId="firstName"
        name="firstName"
        value={name.firstName}
        onChange={handleName}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        inputId="surname"
        name="surname"
        value={name.surname}
        onChange={handleName}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```